# C++ matrix multiplication

Tags: c++

I would like to create a matrix multiplication by a vector algorithm using  registers (of the information in the row-by-row). Open outer loop 4 times
I have problem with 
void matvec_XMM(double* a, double* x, double* y, int n, int lb)
function which return bad result
It is algorithm wchich I must use :

```
i = 1,n,4
   r0 = r1 = r2 = r3 = 0
   j = 1,n,8
      r0 = r0 + aij * xj + ai,j+1 * xj+1 + … + ai,j+7 * xj+7
      r1 = r1 + ai+1,j * xj + ai+1,j+1 * xj+1 + … + ai+1,j+7 * xj+7
      r2 = r2 + ai+2,j * xj + ai+2,j+1 * xj+1 + … + ai+2,j+7 * xj+7
      r3 = r3 + ai+3,j * xj + ai+3,j+1 * xj+1 + … + ai+3,j+7 * xj+7
   end j
   yi = r0; yi+1 = r1; yi+2 = r2; yi+3 = r3; 
end i
```

It is ma code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mvec.h"
#include <emmintrin.h>

using namespace std;

void mult_naive(double *a, double *x, double *y, int n)
{
    int i, j, ij;
    double register reg;

    for(i=0, ij=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        reg = 0;

        for(j=0; j<n; ++j, ++ij)
        {
            reg += a[ij]*x[j];
        }

        y[i] = reg;
    }
}

void matvec_XMM(double* a, double* x, double* y, int n, int lb)
{
int i, j;

memset((void *)y, 0, n*sizeof(double));
double res0[2];
double res1[2];
double res2[2];
double res3[2];

__m128d ry0, ry1, ry2, ry3, ra0, rx0;
double *ptr_a, *ptr_x, *ptr_y;
const int nr = 4;

ptr_a = a;

for (i = 0; i < n; i+=nr)   
{
    ry0 = _mm_setzero_pd();
    ry1 = _mm_setzero_pd();
    ry2 = _mm_setzero_pd();
    ry3 = _mm_setzero_pd(); 

    ptr_y = &y[i];
    ptr_x = x;

    for (j = 0; j<n; j+=lb)
    {

        _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_a + lb*nr), _MM_HINT_NTA); 
        _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_x + lb), _MM_HINT_T0);

        //----1
        rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x);       
        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 2); 
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 4);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 6);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra0);

            //----2
        rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 2);   
        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 8);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 10);  
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 12);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 14);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra0);

        //----3
        rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 4);       
        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 16);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 20);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 22);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra0);

        //----4
        rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 6);       
        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 24);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 26);  
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 28);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra0);

        ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a + 30);
        ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
        ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra0);

        ptr_a += lb*nr;
        ptr_x += lb;
    }

    _mm_store_pd(res0, ry0);
    *ptr_y = res0[0] + res0[1];

    _mm_store_pd(res1, ry1);
    *(ptr_y + 1) = res1[0] + res1[1];

    _mm_store_pd(res2, ry2);
    *(ptr_y + 2)= res2[0] + res2[1];

    _mm_store_pd(res3, ry3);
    *(ptr_y + 3) = res3[0] + res3[1];

}
}



#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "windows.h"
#include "mvec.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double *a, *x, *y, *z;
    int n;
    DWORD tstart;
    const int lb = 8;
    double elaps_time;
    cout << "Program Mat_Vect: performance y = y +A*x\n";

#ifdef _DEBUG
    cout << "DEBUG version\n";
#else
    cout << "RELEASE version\n";
#endif

    cout << "Input dimension\n";
    cin >> n;

    n = n/lb;
    n = lb*n;

    try
    {
        a = new double [n*n];
        x = new double [n+1];
        y = new double [n];
        z = new double [n];
    }
    catch(bad_alloc aa)
    {
        cout << "memory allocation error" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((void *)a, 0, _msize((void *)a));
    memset((void *)x, 0, _msize((void *)x));
    memset((void *)y, 0, _msize((void *)y));

    cout << "start\n";

    prepare(a, x, n);

    //-------------------------naive algorithm-----------------------//
    cout << "naive algorithm: \n";
    tstart = GetTickCount();
    mult_naive(a, x, z, n);
    elaps_time = (double)(GetTickCount()-tstart)/1000.0;
    cout << "naive algorithm: " << elaps_time << " sec" << endl;

    //-------------------------algorithm which uses XMM registers-----------------------//
    delete [] a;
    delete [] x;
    a = (double *)_aligned_malloc(n*n*sizeof(double), 16);
    x = (double *)_aligned_malloc(n*sizeof(double), 16);
    if(!a || !x)
    {
        cout << "memory allocation error" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "algorithm which uses XMM: \n";
    prepare(a, x, n);
    tstart = GetTickCount();
    matvec_XMM(a, x, y, n, lb);
    elaps_time = (double)(GetTickCount()-tstart)/1000.0;
    check(y, z, n);
    cout << "algorithm which uses XMM: " << elaps_time << " sec" << endl;

    delete [] y;
    delete [] z;
    _aligned_free(a);
    _aligned_free(x);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void check(double *y, double *z, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(fabs(z[i] - y[i]) > 1.0e-9)
        {
            cout << "error\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    cout << "OK\n";
}

void prepare(double *a, double *x, int n)
{
    int i, j, ij;

    for(i=0, ij=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++, ij++)
        {
            if(i == j)
                a[ij] = 10.0;
            else
                a[ij] = (double)(i+1);
        }

        x[i] = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: They code you show isnt sufficient to reproduce the problem, because you do not show how you call this function and it is unclear what you mean with "bad result"

Comment: Please be more specific on the problem you encounter. What is the purpose of the parameter `lb`? Do you aim at storing the first matrix row-major and the second one column-major?

Comment: Could anyone tell me _why are lots of people multiplying matrices_? What for? Do we often use them in IT?

Comment: ;p it's useful for example in FEM (finite-element method)

Comment: @ForceBru They're very useful in 3D graphics too.

Comment: make sure to precise that you are really doing (nxn ) x (nx1) matrix multiplication. Because I was already screaming in my head ***"O(n^2) algorithm for matrix multiplication?? Quick, write a patent!!"***

Comment: I added the algorithm to be used

Comment: To my mind, it would be pretty difficult to answer this as there's _too much_ code. Please provide a _Minimal_ working example. Which result is _bad_ for you?

Comment: all code is ok, the problem is in this function : void matvec_XMM(double* a, double* x, double* y, int n, int lb)  , this function returns bad results

Comment: @ForceBru matrices are *extremely* important in engineering, physics, maths and many facets of computer science, I'm an engineer and we use them all the time. Linear algebra is fundamental to a lot of problems.

Comment: any ideas to solve this problem  ?

Comment: Why don't you just use an existing LA package which is guaranteed to give *good* results?

Comment: Because it was my academic program and I had to solve it in this way :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
void matvec_XMM(double* a, double* x, double* y, int n, int lb)
{
    int i, j;

    memset((void *)y, 0, n*sizeof(double));
    __declspec(align(16)) double res0[2];
    __declspec(align(16)) double res1[2];
    __declspec(align(16)) double res2[2];
    __declspec(align(16)) double res3[2];

    __m128d ry0, ry1, ry2, ry3, ra0, ra1, ra2, ra3, rx0;
    double *ptr_a1, *ptr_a2, *ptr_a3, *ptr_a4, *ptr_x, *ptr_y;
    const int nr = 4;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i+=nr)
    {
        ry0 = _mm_setzero_pd();
        ry1 = _mm_setzero_pd();
        ry2 = _mm_setzero_pd();
        ry3 = _mm_setzero_pd();

        ptr_y = &y[i];

        for (j = 0; j<n; j+=lb)
        {
            ptr_a1 = &a[i * n + j];
            ptr_a2 = &a[(i + 1) * n + j];
            ptr_a3 = &a[(i + 2) * n + j];
            ptr_a4 = &a[(i + 3) * n + j];
            ptr_x = &x[j];

            _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_a1 + lb), _MM_HINT_NTA);
            _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_a2 + lb), _MM_HINT_NTA);
            _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_a3 + lb), _MM_HINT_NTA);
            _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_a4 + lb), _MM_HINT_NTA);
            _mm_prefetch((const char *)(ptr_x + lb), _MM_HINT_T0);

            //-------------------------------------1
            rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x);

            ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a1);
            ra1 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a2);
            ra2 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a3);
            ra3 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a4);

            ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
            ra1 = _mm_mul_pd(ra1, rx0);
            ra2 = _mm_mul_pd(ra2, rx0);
            ra3 = _mm_mul_pd(ra3, rx0);

            ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);
            ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra1);
            ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra2);
            ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra3);

            //------------------------------------2
            rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 2);

            ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a1 + 2);
            ra1 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a2 + 2);
            ra2 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a3 + 2);
            ra3 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a4 + 2);

            ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
            ra1 = _mm_mul_pd(ra1, rx0);
            ra2 = _mm_mul_pd(ra2, rx0);
            ra3 = _mm_mul_pd(ra3, rx0);

            ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);
            ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra1);
            ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra2);
            ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra3);

            //-----------------------------------3
            rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 4);

            ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a1 + 4);
            ra1 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a2 + 4);
            ra2 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a3 + 4);
            ra3 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a4 + 4);

            ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
            ra1 = _mm_mul_pd(ra1, rx0);
            ra2 = _mm_mul_pd(ra2, rx0);
            ra3 = _mm_mul_pd(ra3, rx0);

            ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);
            ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra1);
            ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra2);
            ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra3);

            //----------------------------------4
            rx0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_x + 6);

            ra0 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a1 + 6);
            ra1 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a2 + 6);
            ra2 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a3 + 6);
            ra3 = _mm_load_pd(ptr_a4 + 6);

            ra0 = _mm_mul_pd(ra0, rx0);
            ra1 = _mm_mul_pd(ra1, rx0);
            ra2 = _mm_mul_pd(ra2, rx0);
            ra3 = _mm_mul_pd(ra3, rx0);

            ry0 = _mm_add_pd(ry0, ra0);
            ry1 = _mm_add_pd(ry1, ra1);
            ry2 = _mm_add_pd(ry2, ra2);
            ry3 = _mm_add_pd(ry3, ra3);
        }

        _mm_store_pd(res0, ry0);
        *ptr_y = res0[0] + res0[1];

        _mm_store_pd(res1, ry1);
        *(ptr_y + 1) = res1[0] + res1[1];

        _mm_store_pd(res2, ry2);
        *(ptr_y + 2) = res2[0] + res2[1];

        _mm_store_pd(res3, ry3);
        *(ptr_y + 3) = res3[0] + res3[1];
    }
}
```